# JQuery - .is in an if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm trying to use .is() in an IF statement but its showing:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'

*example code:*

```
if ("#id > table > tbody").children().is("tr.abc")  {

  $("#id").css("display", "none")
  }
```

Can the boolean logic in .is() be used in IF statements?

Thank you

Comment: Just fix the syntax error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can, but you need your statement wrapped in parentheses.

```
if ($("#id > table > tbody").children().is("tr.abc"))  {
   ^^                                               ^
```

FYI this is not specific to jquery at all; just required javascript syntax.  There are lots of good resources for learning javascript, but https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript is a good starting point if you're looking for one!

Comment: As in the OP's code, you're also missing the `$`

Comment: Yep.  Thanks for the heads up!